# SpaCy NLP- Detect the verb form

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

As far as I know that we can get the v1 form of a verb using

```
word.lemma_
```

I wanted to know is their a way in which we can get the form of the verb like:

*swims* it should output v4

Is their way to do that using SpaCy or any other lib and if there is then please give a link to that command

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 6 verb forms available in spacy:

```
VB  --  verb, base form
VBD  --  verb, past tense
VBG  --  verb, gerund or present participle
VBN  --  verb, past participle
VBP  --  verb, non-3rd person singular present
VBZ  --  verb, 3rd person singular present
```

This is what you can get by calling `word.tag_`. However, I don't know how they relate to your v1 or v4. To find all tags just call:

```
for label in nlp.get_pipe("tagger").labels:
    print(label, " -- ", spacy.explain(label))
```